# Linkedin 401 Error via python

Tags: python, linkedin-api, oauth-2.0

Trying to access LinkedIn Developer API using Python but getting 401 error while invoking linkedin API. Could you please assist -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "user_request.py", line 33, in <module>
    print app.get_profile()
  File "/Users/bchawla/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/linkedin/linkedin.py", line 179, in get_profile
    raise_for_error(response)
  File "/Users/bchawla/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/linkedin/utils.py", line 63, in raise_for_error
    raise LinkedInError(message)
linkedin.exceptions.LinkedInError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~: Unknown Error
```

The detailed code is as under -

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import urlparse
from linkedin import linkedin

consumer_key           = "{Key}"
consumer_secret        = "{Secret}"
consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer)

request_token_url      = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken'
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "POST")
if resp['status'] != '200':
    raise Exception("Invalid response %s." % resp['status'])

print content

request_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))

print "    - oauth_token        = %s" % request_token['oauth_token']
print "    - oauth_token_secret = %s" % request_token['oauth_token_secret']


auth = linkedin.LinkedInDeveloperAuthentication(consumer_key, consumer_secret,
request_token['oauth_token'], request_token['oauth_token_secret'], '',
permissions=linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())

print linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values()

app = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(auth)

print app.get_profile()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The majority of the old linkedin APIs, including the people API that you are attempting to use, have been depreciated and restricted solely to pre-approved developers - you now need to be part of their development program (which is limited to a very small set of companies they actively work with).

See: https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api

> People Search API is a part of our Vetted API Access Program. You must apply here and get LinkedIn's approval before using this API.

See also:  https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

> Starting on May 12, 2015, we will be limiting the open APIs to only
>   support the following uses:
>
> - Allowing members to represent their professional identity via their
>     LinkedIn profile using our Profile API.
> - Enabling members to post
>     certifications directly to their LinkedIn profile with our Add to
>     Profile tools.
> - Enabling members to share professional content to their
>     LinkedIn network from across the Web leveraging our Share API.
> - Enabling companies to share professional content to LinkedIn with our
>     Company API.

This is consistent with the error code that you are receiving - `401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.` - given you are not part their developer program, you do not have valid credentials to access it.